# Formula Field return minimum date?

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am trying to write a formula that returns the minimum date (or earliest) out of these three date fields:

```
MIN(
Year(Year_One_Start_Date__c),
Year(Year_Two_Start_Date__c),
Year(Year_Three_Start_Date__c)
)
```

I get an error when I run check syntax in the formula builder that says:

`Error: Formula result is data type (Number), incompatible with expected data type (Date).`

I tried wrapping the formula in the DateValue function, but that didn't work either.

Example Dates:

```
12/10/2022 - Year_One_Start_Date__c
12/15/2022 - Year_Two_Start_Date__c
12/18/2022 - Year_Three_Start_Date__c
```

Based on this sample data, the result of the formula would return a date value of 12/10/2022

How can I modify my existing formula and get the correct output?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error should give you a decent hint as to why it's not working.

`MIN()` takes number arguments, and returns a `Number`.
You configured your formula to return a `Date`.
Since `Number` != `Date`, you get an error

Even if you were able to get the minimum year (assuming that the years of all 3 dates are different, which they aren't in your example), that doesn't tell you which date to pull the month and day components from.

It's *probably* possible to get the minimum date using that approach, but `MIN()` isn't really the right tool for this job.

Instead, just use the normal comparison operators (<, <=, >, >=, ==, !=). They can be used with Dates and Datetimes. Since you only have 3 dates, doing this with comparison operators and `IF()` is simple enough.

- Check if date 1 < date 2

  - if true, then check if date 1 < date 3

    - if true, return date 1
    - else return date 3
  - else check if date 2 < date 3

    - if true, return date 2
    - else return date 3

Going much beyond that though would be really unwieldy. Formulas are only really suited for the most simple of date/time manipulations. In that case, using a before-save record-triggered flow would be a better idea.

+edit:
After another look through [Formula Operators and Functions By Context](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5), `UNIXTIMESTAMP()` could help out here. It turns Dates/Datetimes into a number (seconds since 1970-01-01) which you could feed into `MIN()`. You could then feed the result of `MIN()`
into `CASE()` to get back to a Date/Datetime.

A bit of a roundabout solution, but it would scale to higher numbers of Date/Datetime fields (though really, a flow would probably still be better).
As a pseudo-formula

```
CASE(
    /* first arg, returns the minimum date/datetime as a number */
    MIN(UNIXTIMESTAMP(date 1), UNIXTIMESTAMP(date2), ..., UNIXTIMESTAMP(date n)),
    /* each subsequent argument pair maps a timestamp back to its date */
    UNIXTIMESTAMP(date 1), date 1,
    UNIXTIMESTAMP(date 2), date 2,
    ...
    UNIXTIMESTAMP(date n), date n,
    null /* default value, required */
)
```

Using `CASE()` is required for this approach (at time of writing) because Salesforce doesn't give us a function to go from a timestamp back to a date/datetime (and doing the calculations manually would become unwieldy).